# What is the meaning of " can have made" in this text?

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Neither Ammianus nor Zosimus makes the slightest allusion to any negotiations at all at this period; and it is thus open to doubt whether the entire story told by Libanius is not the product of his imagination. But at any rate it is quite impossible that the Persian king can have made any abject offers of submission, or have been in a state of mind at all akin to despair.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Answer (score 1):

The verb phrase, unmodified is "make an offer of submission".  To "make and offer" means to propose something, and to make an offer of submission means to propose to resign or accept defeat.

Then "has made an offer..." is the perfect tense (current state, but here an historical present tense is being used, we are telling a story about the past, but using the present tense, as it the events described are happening now).  And "can have made an offer" is the usual meaning of "can" (something is possible)

Reading the the whole sentence we see it is "impossible",  so we are certain that the king can't have made an offer of submission.

Here is another example in the same verb form.

> It is impossible that he can have eaten the whole cake.  It was too big for one person.

Comment: I find it odd that these counter-factual clauses are cast in the present indicative.  The situation seems neither, and the phrasing strikes my American ear awkwardly, at best.